# Передвижение персонажа в Unity

Tags: c#, unity3d

Когда я поворачиваю персонажа на 90 градусов вправо, то при нажатии на W он идет влево, а не прямо (до поворота всё нормально)

```
public class MyPlayer : MonoBehaviour {
    public float speed;
    private Rigidbody rb;
    public MyJoystick joystick;

    void Start() {
        rb = GetComponent<Rigidbody>();
    }

    /*void FixedUpdate () {
        //Vector3 movement = new Vector3 (joystick.Horizontal () * Time.deltaTime, 0.0f, joystick.Vertical() * Time.deltaTime);
        //rb.velocity = movement * speed;
        this.gameObject.transform.position += this.gameObject.transform.forward * Time.deltaTime * (speed * joystick.Vertical());
        this.gameObject.transform.position += this.gameObject.transform.right * Time.deltaTime * (speed * joystick.Horizontal());
    }*/
    void FixedUpdate()
    {
        Vector3 movement = new Vector3(joystick.Horizontal(), 0, joystick.Vertical());

        rb.velocity = movement.normalized * speed;
    }
}
```

Изначально я использовал код, который закомментирован, но там персонаж проходил сквозь коллайдеры.

Код джойстика (не изменял):

```
public class MyRotationTouchpad : MonoBehaviour
{

    public Transform RotatableH;
    public Transform RotatableV;
    public float RotationSpeed = .1f;
    public bool InvertedV = true;
    public bool ClampedV = true;

    Vector2 currentMousePosition;
    Vector2 mouseDeltaPosition;
    Vector2 lastMousePosition;
    
    public static MyRotationTouchpad mrt;
    [HideInInspector]
    public bool istouchpadactive;

    private void Start()
    {
        mrt = this;
        ResetMousePosition();
    }

    public void ResetMousePosition()
    {
        if(Input.touchCount == 1){
            if(!MyJoystick.js.started){
                currentMousePosition = Input.GetTouch(0).position;
            }
        }else if(Input.touchCount == 2){
            
            if(MyJoystick.js.started){
                currentMousePosition = Input.GetTouch(1).position;
            }else{
                currentMousePosition = Input.GetTouch(0).position;
            }
        }else{
            currentMousePosition = Input.mousePosition;
        }
        
        lastMousePosition = currentMousePosition;
        mouseDeltaPosition = currentMousePosition - lastMousePosition;
    }

    void LateUpdate()
    {
        if (istouchpadactive)
        {
            if(Input.touchCount == 1){
                if(!MyJoystick.js.started){
                    currentMousePosition = Input.GetTouch(0).position;
                }
            }else if(Input.touchCount == 2){
                
                if(MyJoystick.js.started){
                    currentMousePosition = Input.GetTouch(1).position;
                }else{
                    currentMousePosition = Input.GetTouch(0).position;
                }
            }else{
                currentMousePosition = Input.mousePosition;
            }
            
            
            mouseDeltaPosition = currentMousePosition - lastMousePosition;

            if (RotatableH != null)
                RotatableH.transform.Rotate(0f, mouseDeltaPosition.x * RotationSpeed, 0f);
            if (RotatableV != null)
            {
                
                
                if (InvertedV){
                    RotatableV.transform.Rotate(Mathf.Clamp(mouseDeltaPosition.y * (RotationSpeed * -1), -3, 3), 0f, 0f);
                }
                    
                else{
                    RotatableV.transform.Rotate(Mathf.Clamp(mouseDeltaPosition.y * RotationSpeed, -3, 3), 0f, 0f);
                }

                
                if(ClampedV){
                    float limitedXRot = RotatableV.transform.localEulerAngles.x;
                    if(limitedXRot > 45f && limitedXRot < 320f){
                        if(limitedXRot < 180f)
                            limitedXRot = 45f;
                        else
                            limitedXRot = 320f;
                        
                    }                   
                    RotatableV.transform.localEulerAngles = new Vector3(limitedXRot, RotatableV.transform.localEulerAngles.y, RotatableV.transform.localEulerAngles.z);
                }
                
            }

            lastMousePosition = currentMousePosition;


        }


    }

    public void ActivateTouchpad()
    {
        ResetMousePosition();
        istouchpadactive = true;
    }

    public void DeactivateTouchpad()
    {
        istouchpadactive = false;
    }
}
```

В чём может быть проблема?

Comment: попробую помочь, но сначала
1. "Когда я поворачиваю персонажа на 90 градусов вправо" - где реализация этого поворота, чтоб можно было проверить?
2. Влево/вправо - это что значит? Это относительно персонажа? Или относительно вьюпорта (экрана)?